# Broken line if using glTranslate

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw a line strip on an opengl project.

If I use the glTranslatef function to the transformation matrix, the magenta line strip is drawn broken as show in the figure:

[image: Broken line]

And moving the view, the line strip is broken in different points, or drawn correctly, or not drawn at all.

If I translate manually the points, the line strip is always displayed correctly.

The other lines (red ones: GL_LINE_LOOP, cyan ones: GL_LINES) are manually translated and work properly.

Here is the code with glTranslate:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef( offs_x, offs_y, 0);

glLineWidth(2.0f);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, trailPoints );
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP,0,numTrailPoints);

glPopMatrix();
```

and here the working code with manual translation:

```
for (i=0; i< numTrailPoints; i++)
{
  translatedTrailPoints[i].x = trailPoints[i].x + offs_x;
  translatedTrailPoints[i].y = trailPoints[i].y + offs_y;
  translatedTrailPoints[i].z = trailPoints[i].z;
}

glLineWidth(2.0f);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, translatedTrailPoints);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP,0,numTrailPoints);
```

What I am missing here?

**EDIT :**

To complete the question, here are the data structures (in inverted declaration order for better readability):

```
vec3 translatedTrailPoints[C_MAX_NUM_OF_TRAIL_POINTS];
vec3 trailPoints[C_MAX_NUM_OF_TRAIL_POINTS];

typedef union 
{ 
    float array[3];
    struct { float x,y,z; };
    struct { float r,g,b; };
    struct { float s,t,p; };
    struct { vec2 xy; float zz; };
    struct { vec2 rg; float bb; };
    struct { vec2 st; float pp; };
    struct { float xx; vec2 yz; };
    struct { float rr; vec2 gb; };
    struct { float ss; vec2 tp; };
    struct { float theta, phi, radius; };
    struct { float width, height, depth; };
    struct { float longitude, latitude, altitude; };
    struct { float pitch, yaw, roll; };
} vec3;

typedef union 
{ 
    float array[2];
    struct { float x,y; };
    struct { float s,t; };
} vec2;
```

I'd like to second datenwolf's suggestion, but with no success: I tried pragma pack(1 | 2 | 4) before vec2 and vec3 declaration, I tried compiling with /Zp1 | /Zp2 | /Zp4 (I'm under VisualStudio 2008) but the broken line/points still persists.

**EDIT2 :**

Same problems with textured quads:

```
vec3 point;
point.x = lon;
point.y = lat;
point.z = 500;

glTranslatef( offs_x, offs_y, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, iconTextures[0]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(point.x-C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE, point.y-C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE,  point.z);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(point.x+C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE, point.y-C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE,  point.z);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(point.x+C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE, point.y+C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE,  point.z);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(point.x-C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE, point.y+C_ICON_WORLD_SIZE,  point.z);
glEnd();
```

Results changing the view:

[Correct drawn](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/10326080.png/)

[Bad 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/56541279.png/)

[Bad 2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/221/71036476.png/)

**EDIT3 :**

I was able to correct the textured quads case by translating by (point.x + offs_x, point.y + offs_y, point.z) and removing the point coordinates in the glVertex definitions. The behaviour in the previous mode still puzzles me.

Comment: What's in `trailPoints` itself. You're using GL_LINE_STRIP. In combination with an unhappy geometrical arrangement in the vertex data this might lead to strange effects.

Comment: I'm still lost, trailPoints contains an ordered list of 3d point (x,y,z) in world coordinates.The problem exists with any of these primitives I tested (GL_LINES, GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP, GL_POINTS), here is a screenshot for GL_POINTS: (http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7018/pointsbroken.png)

Comment: Well, how is this list defined? The memory layout of C struct-s is not specified and the compiler may add gaps as it desires (unless you force it into a packed layout).

Comment: Have you tried disabling depth test before rendering your line strip so that it cannot interfere with your background? ...glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

Comment: I tried disabling the depth test, but it did not helped as the light blue background is empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Try using glLoadIdentity() between the glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() calls since it resets the coordinate system and applies the translation for a fresh matrix.

Comment: I tried this; but I have to rotate and translate the modelview matrix after LoadIdentity to get into my correct transformation (if not, I could not see anything), but the result is always the broken line